# Setting a connection timeout with Mysql Ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby, configuration, connection-timeout

I'm working with mysql (5.1) ruby (1.8.7) connector to extract some data from a database. Some queries tend to run longer than desired, so I'd like to set a connection timeout on these. A solution proposed by a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480780/how-do-i-set-the-activerecord-query-timeout-for-mysql) is the following:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mysql'

# connect to the database
db = Mysql.real_connect( 'server', 'user', 'password', 'schema' )

# configure read timeout
db.options(Mysql::OPT_READ_TIMEOUT, 10)

# query and process
begin

  db.query("select * from ..").each_hash do |row|
    # process data if query returned 
  end

rescue Mysql::Error => err
  # handle timeout
end
```

However, this doesn't seem to work for me. Any ideas why and how to accomplish what I'm after? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have to set the options before actually connecting.

```
db = Mysql.init
db.options(Mysql::OPT_READ_TIMEOUT, 10)
db.real_connect( 'server', 'user', 'password', 'schema' )
```