# Set Timeout Value for SQL query in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to execute a very long query in Rails using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)`.

However, the query keeps timing out. Is it possible to change the timeout value for this specific query instead of having to change the timeout value for all queries in `database.yml`?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
# in database.yml
production: &prod
  adapter: whatever
  timeout: 5000 

long_connection_production:
  <<: prod
  timeout: 10000

# app/models/long_connection.rb
class LongConnection < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection "long_connection_#{Rails.env}"

  def self.do_thing_that_takes_a_long_time
    connection.execute(sql)
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't see where there is official documentation for this, I have tried at the [Rails guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html) and to the [mysql2 gem documentation](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2). I only see a reference to the `timeout` variable when you are configuring a sqlite3 db. Also there is not clear is here you are defining the _connection timeout_ of the _query execution timeout_.

Comment: Definitely `timeout` is not working for me with `mysql2` gem connection. I have set up `timeout: 1` and I have a sentence `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(SQL)` that takes more that 2 seconds without any Timeout error

Comment: @fguillen This is a pretty old answer, and I think I tested with the `mysql` gem (and maybe SQLserver), but it seems with the `mysql2` gem, you might need to set the `wait_timeout` key instead of `timeout`.

Comment: looks like `wait_timeout` is for [The number of seconds the server waits for activity on a noninteractive connection before closing it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout). There is not a clear way to set the time out for a query in Rails + MySQL, or at least I haven't found any yet. I think is important that we notice this and that we declare this answer as not correct or it can bring a lot of headaches.. as the one I have now ;)

Comment: @fguillen Have you tried setting `read_timeout` and `write_timeout`?

Comment: I added an [answer with my findings](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37937788/316700).

Answer (score 11):

We have to be careful with the *timeout* variables, most of them are related to *connection* timeouts and not for the query timeout itself.

Looks like until MySQL 5.7.4 the only way to kill a long query was through the [mysql command `kill`](https://serverfault.com/questions/401828/how-to-automatically-kill-slow-mysql-queries-after-n-seconds) which I am not sure if you also will lost the connection client/server so maybe your Rails process will become unusable.

In MySQL 5.7.4 appears the system variable [max_statement_time](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_statement_time) which allows to configure the server exactly to what the original question is asking *"The execution timeout for SELECT statements"*.

To set this system variable through Rails you can use the option [variables](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/MysqlAdapter.html) is your `database.yml`.

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  [...]
  variables:
    max_statement_time: 60000 # 1 minute
```

To check that the variable has been set properly in your ActiveRecord connection you can run this in a Rails console:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('show variables like "%max_execution_time%"').to_a
```

PS: the system variable is renamed to [max_execution_time](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_execution_time) in MySQL 5.7.8

PS2: I have not any access to a MySQL >= 5.7.4 so I can not test these conclusions, I will appreciate if someone confirms it.

Comment: FYI for MySQL 5.6.10 it results in `Mysql2::Error: Unknown system variable 'max_statement_time'`