# how to set query timeout for oracle 11 in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, activerecord, timeout

I saw other threads stating how to do it for mySql, and even how to do it in java, but not how to set the query timeout in ruby.

I'm trying to use the setQueryTimeout function in Jruby using OJDBC7, but can't find how to do it in ruby.  I've tried the following:

```
@c.connection.instance_variable_get(:@connection).instance_variable_set(:@query_timeout, 1)
@c.connection.instance_variable_get(:@connection).instance_variable_set(:@read_timeout, 1)
@c.connection.setQueryTimeout(1)
```

I also tried modifying my database.yml file to include

```
adapter: jdbc
  driver: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
  timeout: 1
```

none of the above had any effect, other then the setQueryTimeout which threw a method error.

Any help would be great

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938691/set-timeout-value-for-sql-query-in-rails

Comment: @Octopus-Paul tried and didn't work

Answer (score 1):

**Query timeout on Oracle-DB works for me with Rails 4 and JRuby**

With JRuby you can use JBDC-function statement.setQueryTimeout to define query timeout.

Suddenly this requires patching of oracle-enhanced_adapter as shown below.
This example is an implementation of iterator-query without storing result in array, which also uses query timeout.

```
# hold open SQL-Cursor and iterate over SQL-result without storing whole result in Array
# Peter Ramm, 02.03.2016

# expand class by getter to allow access on internal variable @raw_statement
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::OracleEnhancedJDBCConnection::Cursor.class_eval do
  def get_raw_statement
    @raw_statement
  end
end

# Class extension by Module-Declaration : module ActiveRecord, module ConnectionAdapters, module OracleEnhancedDatabaseStatements
# does not work as Engine with Winstone application server, therefore hard manipulation of class ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::OracleEnhancedAdapter
# and extension with method iterate_query

ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::OracleEnhancedAdapter.class_eval do

  # Method comparable with ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::OracleEnhancedDatabaseStatements.exec_query,
  # but without storing whole result in memory
  def iterate_query(sql, name = 'SQL', binds = [], modifier = nil, query_timeout = nil, &block)
    type_casted_binds = binds.map { |col, val|
      [col, type_cast(val, col)]
    }
    log(sql, name, type_casted_binds) do
      cursor = nil
      cached = false
      if without_prepared_statement?(binds)
        cursor = @connection.prepare(sql)
      else
        unless @statements.key? sql
          @statements[sql] = @connection.prepare(sql)
        end

        cursor = @statements[sql]

        binds.each_with_index do |bind, i|
          col, val = bind
          cursor.bind_param(i + 1, type_cast(val, col), col)
        end

        cached = true
      end

      cursor.get_raw_statement.setQueryTimeout(query_timeout) if query_timeout

      cursor.exec

      if name == 'EXPLAIN' and sql =~ /^EXPLAIN/
        res = true
      else
        columns = cursor.get_col_names.map do |col_name|
          @connection.oracle_downcase(col_name).freeze
        end
        fetch_options = {:get_lob_value => (name != 'Writable Large Object')}
        while row = cursor.fetch(fetch_options)
          result_hash = {}
          columns.each_index do |index|
            result_hash[columns[index]] = row[index]
            row[index] = row[index].strip if row[index].class == String   # Remove possible 0x00 at end of string, this leads to error in Internet Explorer
          end
          result_hash.extend SelectHashHelper
          modifier.call(result_hash)  unless modifier.nil?
          yield result_hash
        end
      end

      cursor.close unless cached
      nil
    end
  end #iterate_query


end #class_eval




class SqlSelectIterator

  def initialize(stmt, binds, modifier, query_timeout)
    @stmt           = stmt
    @binds          = binds
    @modifier       = modifier              # proc for modifikation of record
    @query_timeout  = query_timeout
  end

  def each(&block)
    # Execute SQL and call block for every record of result
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.iterate_query(@stmt, 'sql_select_iterator', @binds, @modifier, @query_timeout, &block)
  end

end
```

Use above class SqlSelectIterator like this example:

```
SqlSelectIterator.new(stmt, binds, modifier, query_timeout).each do |record|
  process(record) 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found a way to make it work, but I don't like it.  It's very hackish and orphans queries on the database, but it at least allows my app to continue executing.  I would still love to find a way to cancel the statement so i'm not orphaning queries that take longer then 10 seconds.

```
query_thread = Thread.new {
   #execute query
}

begin
  Timeout::timeout(10) do
    query_thread.join()
  end
rescue
  Thread.kill(query_thread)
  results = Array.new
end
```